# Expo Barcode Scanner is only scanning QR codes

Tags: react-native, expo, barcode-scanner

I have an expo react native app to scan simcard numbers.  Currently the app is only scanning qr codes and will not scan any other bar codes.  I have also searched random bar codes on the internet and the only one it will take is QR codes.  I know the `barCodeTypes` prop takes an array of possible bar code types it can scan.  I passed in literally all of them and it still only scans QR codes. I am on a windows 10 computer.  Here is my code.

```js
    if(scanning) {
      console.log(BarCodeScanner.Constants.BarCodeType)
      return (
        <View style={styles.scanner}>
          <BarCodeScanner
            onBarCodeScanned={this.scanBarcode}
            barCodeTypes={Object.values(BarCodeScanner.Constants.BarCodeType)}
            style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}>
            <Text>Scan your simcard</Text>
            <Text onPress={() => this.setState({ scanning: false })} style={styles.cancel}>
              Cancel
            </Text>
          </BarCodeScanner>
        </View>
      )
    }
    return (
```

Here is an example of the bar code that I am trying to scan.  It is the long one on the right, visible through the small window on the back of the simcard.

[Image](https://cdn-cosmos.bluesoft.com.br/products/5060172543120)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try omitting the `barCodeTypes` property. By default, it should include all of them. [The docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/#props) say "Defaults to all supported bar code types." for the `barCodeTypes` prop.